# PCIe Bus Error and lightdm module uninstalled

Tags: apt, python, sudo, lightdm

Need a little help.
I've Ubuntu 18.04 installed which had python 2.7 initially.
Instead of updating I installed 3.6 separately without taking proper precautions and it wreaked havoc on my system.
So i used following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge -auto--remove python
```

Same i did for 3.6. 
Same for `pip` and `pip3.6`.

But all this somehow deleted my gui and now on restarting I find only tty

I tried

```
sudo apt-get reinstall lightdm
```

It installed the required gui modules but even with correct password, the login would display 'failed to start session' .

I pressed ctrl+alt+f1 at control window and tried changing user as well but to no avail.

So right now I've removed lightdm using

```
sudo apt-get remove lightdm
```

Now I don't have a gui, only a TTY is displayed and my credentials are working fine there.

**But a PCIe bus error is being displayed continuously.**

My system also had a separate python 3.
So 3 pythons in total which messed up my environment so I did all this :P

I found out that this PCIe bus error is because of improper support by HP for Linux and these mere warnings can be removed by adding an argument in the grub file and updating it there after.

Is there any way I can just delete everything on my system and reinstall Ubuntu from scratch?

Comment: Many Ubuntu resources rely on `python` (2.7 for 18.04), plus `python3` is installed by default for Ubuntu 18.04 and accessed via python3.  You can get problems when you change defaults on system tools unless you avoid those tools. Yes you can re-install (I'd suggest using 'something-else', using existing partitions and not have it format your partition(s) as a quick fix, otherwise I'd reverse whatever python changes you made and use the default `python3` which is 3.6.6 for 18.04 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/python3)

Comment: Hey so now I've installed Ubuntu mate core and I've a gui now, but now I'm stuck in a login loop. I enter password and land on login page again, tryna fix that for now then can I fix this python thing. If you can help with this, ill be grateful. TIA